# RubyOnRails: interface to shell script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make a button inside my GUI that triggers a shell script. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put

```
def action_name
  output = `/path/to/your/shell/script`
end
```

into an action that can be called from the gui.
the backtick operator `` makes a system call and returns the standard output of your shell script.

**UPD**: This is the easy way. If you have a long running shell script you should consider using something like [Delayed::Job](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

Comment: after that script has been invoked, can I safely use a redirect?

Comment: I can't think of anything why not, so I would say yes

Comment: The backticks collect all of the output. So if you redirect after the action it won't be called until after the shell script completes. So the redirect will be fine